# Object Design catalog and resources

Tags: design-patterns, oop

I'm looking for web sites, books, or other resources that provide a catalog of object designs used in common scenarios.  I'm not looking for generic design patterns, but for samples of actual object designs that were used to solve real problems.

For instance, I'm about to build an internal messaging system for a web application, similar to Facebook's messaging system. This system will allow administrators to send messages to all members, to selected groups of members, or to individuals. Members can send messages to other members or groups of members. Fairly common stuff and a feature that I'm sure thousands of web applications require.

I know each situation is different and there are a million ways to design this solution. Although this scenario isn't really all that complex, I'm sure the basic design of the necessary objects and relationships for a system like this has already been done many times. It would be nice to review other similar designs before building my own.

Is there a place where people can share their designs and others can browse/search through the catalog to review and provide feedback on them? StackOverflow could be used to a degree for this, but doesn't really provide a catalog of designs. Any other resources that would relate?

Answer (score 0):

I think that one of the books that provides you with examples of object oriented design solutions to real problems is this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Object-Oriented-Programming-Peter-Coad/dp/013032616X/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_b](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013032616X)